# Why is my disk size reduced and not using the free space of storageSize? ongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
"db" : "nameDatabase",
"collections" : 2,
"views" : 0,
"objects" : 2104394,
"avgObjSize" : 459217.714875161,
"dataSize" : 966375003877.0,
"storageSize" : 466821181440.0,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 2,
"indexSize" : 36229120.0,
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

**dataSize** = Actual size of the information in the database

**storageSize** = dataSize + deleted documents (space free)

**storageSize - dataSize = 499553822437.0**
*free space available to rewrite with new documents. Correct?

Although *db.stats()* indicates those values, if I consult my hard disk the collectionXXX.wt file occupies 394GB and continues to grow... I only have 11GB free (critical).

**How is it possible??** Any solution?

I've used *compact* but it is not freeing up hard disk space.

(Mongodb version version 3.4.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataSize` is the size of your raw data. For example document `{a: false}` has a size of 9 Bytes

`storageSize` is the size of the physical used disk space of your data (without indexes). As you see, your data is [compressed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression) by around 50%

`indexSize` is the size of the physical used disk space of your indexes.

So, all your collectionXXX.wt + indexXXX.wt files should have a size of around 434.8 GiByte

Solution: put in a bigger disk or remove unused data.

Comment: Thanks! Right now I'm applying the following "patch": I select 10,000 documents older than X date (outdated) and delete them from Robo 3T but it takes more than 30 minutes... I do it with a "limit" and not directly "everything before the selected date" for fear of saturating the database or corrupting it. The database is in production / active. 

Do you think that being in use (new records every minute), can I delete all documents from years ago without affecting (stopping the use or corrupting the database)? I don't have much of an idea and I'm worried about causing a disaster.

Comment: You can simply delete old data, but it will take some time. For the future have a look at [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)